# Highest common factor of divisors of a number

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, combinations

> Given that a number is N=2910600 . Find total number of ways in which given number can be split into two factors such that their highest common factor is a prime number .

**my attempt**

$N=2^3 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11$

Now, *one of the number would have only the first power of a prime number and the second number would have the remaining powers of the chosen prime number. The other prime numbers could be multiplied either with factor 1'or factor 2.*

**Example**

Factor 1: $2^1$

Factor 2 : $2^2 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11$

Or

Factor 1: $2^1 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11 $

Factor 2: $2^2$

This makes the answer $2\cdot 5= $**10**

Is my way correct or is there an alternate solution ?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Looking at your factorization, there are only four candidates for the greatest common factor: 2, 3, 5 and 7. Try breaking up into four cases for each of these choices. For example, if 2 if the highest common factor, your factors must look like $2a$ and $4b$, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. There are two ways to pick which factor gets all three 3s, two ways for the 5s, two ways for the 7s, and two ways for the 11, leaving 16 factorizations of this form.

Comment: @JeremyDover thanks .Got my mistake.

Comment: @JeremyDover what about 11 and 264600

Comment: Why are we not including 11?

Comment: Because 11 is not a common factor. These two numbers are relatively prime. Your original number would need to be divisible by $11^2$ for this to happen.

Comment: The number of ways with common factor $2$ will be the same as the number with common factor $3$ because they have the same exponent in the original number.  Similarly for $5$ and $7$.  These two pairs will differ if you care about the order of the factors, as the fives can only be split $5,5$ but the twos can be split $4,2$ or $2,4$.  If you don't care about the order of the factors these do not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $n=ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=p$ for some prime $p$. So $a=a'p$ and $b=b'p$ for some natural numbers $a'$ and $b'$. Hence $N=a'b'p^2$ with $\gcd(a',b')=1$.

So in order to construct all possible pairs $(a,b)$, we pick a prime $p$ and divide $N$ by $p^2$. Then we split the quotient in two coprime factors, $(a',b')$.

Now, $N=2^3\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 11$
So we have $4$ choices for $p$, namely $2$, $3$, $5$ and $7$. If we choose $5$ or $7$, the quotient has $4$ unique prime factors. For each of these we must decide whether they will be a factor of $a'$ or not (meaning they'll be a factor of $b$)'. This gives $2^4$ possible combinations, but some of these will be the same, with $a'$ and $b'$ switched, so we'll divide by $2$ and there are $8$ possible combinations.

If we choose $2$ or $3$ for $p$, there are $5$ unique primes left, so there are $\frac12\cdot 2^5=16$ possible combinations.

This gives a total number of possible ways of:
$$8+8+16+16=48$$ 
different ways.